# Numpy: Insert arbitrary number of zeros into matrix rows at various indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

#### Problem

I have a 2D array that contains a series of 0's and 1's which represent values that have been bit-packed. I need to insert an arbitrary number of 0's at arbitrary points in every row in order to pad the bit-packed values a multiple of 8 bits.

I have 3 vectors.

1. A vector containing indices that I want to insert zeros at
2. A vector containing the number of zeros that I want to insert at each point from vector 1.
3. A vector that contains the size of each bit-string I am padding. (Probably don't need this to solve but it could be fun!)

#### Example

I have a vector that contains indices to insert before: `[0 6 14]`

and a vector that contains the number of zeroes that I want to insert: `[2 0 4]`

and a vector that has the size of each bitstring I am padding: `[6, 8, 4]`

The aim is to insert the zeroes into each row of array as such:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0  0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0  0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 1  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0  0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 0  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0  0 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 1 0  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1 0 0 1]]

*Spaces added between columns to highlight insertion points.
```

Becomes:

```
  | |                               | | | |
  v v                               v v v v
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1]]

*Arrows denote inserted 0's
```

I am trying the most performant way of doing this. All of the vectors/arrays are numpy arrays. I've looked into using `numpy.insert` but that doesn't seem do have the ability to insert multiple values at a given index. I've also thought about using `numpy.hstack` and then flattening, but was unable to yield the result I wanted.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It may be the case that numpy arrays are not quite what you want to use here.  In general, the speed advantages of numpy arrays are lost when you have to keep resizing them.  An alternate formulation that could be faster is representing this as a list of lists, where the `list.extend` command is your friend.

If you post your code, it would be possible to compare the speed advantages using ipythons `%timeit` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`np.insert`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) does support inserting multiple values at the same index, you just have to provide that index multiple times. So you can obtain your desired result as follows:

```py
indices = np.array([0, 6, 14])
n_zeros = np.array([2, 0, 4])

result = np.insert(matrix,
                   np.repeat(indices, n_zeros),
                   0,
                   axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to create a zero array up front and copy the columns into the correct locations. The indexing is a little hairy with respect to clarity, so there is probably room for improvement there.

```py
data = np.array(
  [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,  0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,  0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,  0, 0, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,  0, 0, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,  0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,  0, 1, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,  0, 1, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,  0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,  0, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,  1, 0, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 0, 0, 1]])
insert_before = [0, 6, 14]
zero_pads = [0, 2, 4]

res = np.zeros((len(data), 8*len(zero_pads)), dtype=int)  

for i in range(len(zero_pads)):
    res[:, i*8+zero_pads[i]:(i+1)*8] = data[:, insert_before[i]:insert_before[i]+8-zero_pads[i]]


>>> res
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Formatted the matrix for you (although it might be easier to work with a contrived example):

```
matrix = nparray([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                  [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

```
indices = np.array([0, 6, 14])
num_zeros = np.array([2, 0, 4])
pad = np.array([6, 8, 4])
```

You need to allocate a new array to do this operation. Creating zero-filled arrays in numpy is very cheap. So let's start with allocating a zero filled array with our desired output shape:

```
out_shape = np.array(matrix.shape)
out_shape[1] += num_zeros.sum()
zeros = np.zeros(out_shape, dtype=matrix.dtype)
```

Now, write `matrix` to continuous blocks of memory in `zeros` by using slices:

```
meta = np.stack([indices, num_zeros])
meta = meta[:, meta[1] != 0] # throw away 0 slices
slices = meta.T.ravel().cumsum()
slices = np.append(cs, zeros.shape[1]) # for convenience

prev = 0
for start, end in zip(slices[1::2], slices[2::2]):
    zeros[:, slice(start,end)] = matrix[:, slice(prev, prev + end-start)]
    prev = end-start
```

Output in `zeros`:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1]]
```